# ajax always going to success

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm having troubles with ajax. my code runs well, but then, it always goes to success.

```
dataLogin = 'mail=' + $('#login_mail').val() + '&pass=' + $('#login_password').val() + '&on=' + manter_ligado;

$.ajax({ url: 'modules/login.php?' + dataLogin,
  type: 'POST',
  //data: dataLogin,
  data : {
    mail : $('#login_mail').val(),
    pass : $('#login_password').val(),
    on : manter_ligado
  },
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
  }
});
```

can anyone help me with this?
Also, I'm using sublime to code, and it gives me some errors on the ajax, but I can't seem to correct them, it might help knowing this

Also, I know that the php works, because I can make the login on the website, but the problem I have is when the user/pass is incorrect

Comment: Try only `url: 'modules/login.php'` like in this example (1): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#entry-examples

Comment: What is the web server returning from the AJAX request?

Comment: Worth nothing that it's `error` and not `failure` to declare the failure callback function.

Comment: sorry, that was a late test, now I have error, changed the code to `url: 'modules/login.php'` but it still doesn't get to the error.

Comment: In my destination (modules/login.php) I've even put a function to return true or false, but it didn't solve it

Comment: what is in the `data` returned? and why do you use both POST and GET parameter? can you share a link to the page?

Comment: for example, if I put an alert on success `alert('test')` on success, and one `alert('error')`on error, it always shows me the success one, even if I make it to give me an error.

Comment: yeah, but WHAT exactly is returned by the success handler? what is in the `data` parameter you receive?

Comment: it sends a blank alert, `A página em almadados.dev:8888 indica`

Comment: returning true or false is consider as success because there was no error. if you want ajax call returning error just raise/throw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the server is returning an error code of 500.

In the php.ini file, make sure displayErrors is set to Off

To get the ajax to hit the failure function, you may need to throw an error when one occurs in your PHP

Comment: I've seen and displayErrors is set to Off. I'm totally lost here

Comment: sorry are you using PHP? I just assumed

Comment: If you're not seeing a 500, try putting a `throw new Exception("Test exception");` at the top of your ajax script. (or if its not php, change syntax accordingly). Then see if you get a 500

Comment: it may be my fault here, but when I try to paste your code, the browser gives me an error, is it suppose to happen? it stops my javascript

Comment: Yes, that's the kind of error that will cause the ajax to fail, so if you want the ajax call to call the failure function, you need to throw a similar error, but in the proper location in your code